# Python3 script installed with pip doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, blogger, gdata, pkg-resources

I installed an application with python's "pip":

```
sudo pip install EasyBlogger
```

Installation finished without errors:

```
Collecting EasyBlogger
  Using cached EasyBlogger-0.9.0.zip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pypandoc in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): google-api-python-client in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-gflags in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pypandoc->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauth2client>=1.4.6 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.6.1 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): uritemplate>=0.6 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from oauth2client>=1.4.6->google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from oauth2client>=1.4.6->google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from oauth2client>=1.4.6->google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson>=2.5.0 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from uritemplate>=0.6->google-api-python-client->EasyBlogger)
Installing collected packages: EasyBlogger
  Running setup.py install for EasyBlogger
Successfully installed EasyBlogger-0.9.0
```

However when I try to run the scipt the following way:

```
sudo easyblogger --blogid 6852822618950333369 get
```

I get only error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easyblogger", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('EasyBlogger==0.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'easyblogger')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2720, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2380, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/blogger/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blogger import EasyBlogger, main
ImportError: cannot import name 'EasyBlogger'
```

The content of /usr/bin/easyblogger is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'EasyBlogger==0.9.0','console_scripts','easyblogger'
__requires__ = 'EasyBlogger==0.9.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('EasyBlogger==0.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'easyblogger')()
    )
```

The error comes from the 9. line load_entry_point. What can I do to make the easyblogger script working? Anyway I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: Does `pip` in command `sudo pip install EasyBlogger` is OS wide ?
Try to install new virtualenv, activate  it and repeat that flow without `sudo` within newly created virtualenv. Pretty sure that everything works well in that case.

Comment: Not familiar with easyblogger but a couple of tests might get you further down the road - first, can you do something like easyblogger --version etc to see if it is installed ok. also "which easyblogger" etc. Then if that is working, can you try referencing a different blogid and see whether the issue is local to that particular blog?  Please update your question with these results. In other words, ensure you can pinpoint the issue to the install. Also, why are you using "sudo" for the install and execution commands?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Python 3. It appears `easyblogger` is not compatible, even though it installs using `pip3`.

To see this, correct `__init__.py` by adding a period since your are importing from the current folder (new in python 3):

```
from .blogger import EasyBlogger, main
```

Now if you run your command, you get the following:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/blogger/blogger.py", line 424
    print postId
               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Now you need to decide whether to fix the package or not! Just to make sure, installing in Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install EasyBlogger
```